# Determine if char value is in range of chars

Tags: java, character

The objective is this:

> Row 1: A-L
>   Row 2: M-Z
>
> Write a program that takes as input a student's full name (first last) and prints out the row the student should be in. The first nor last name will contain any spaces. There will be only one space in the input and that will be between the first and last name.

I am not sure how to make it read character A - L and M- Z.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeatingChart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        char row1 = 'A' ,'L';
        char row2 = 'M' ,'Z';

        System.out.println(" Enter the student's last name: ");
        String name = in.next();

        char initial = name.charAt(0);

        if (initial = row1) {
            System.out.println(" This student can sit anywhere in row 1. ");
        }

        if (initial = row2) {
            System.out.println(" This student can sit anywhere in row 2. ");
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, but The code is incorrect for declaring characters A - L and characters M - Z. How would I fix this to make it read these list of characters?

Comment: Added the tag. This is using java. @Frank

Comment: In Java you compare with `==` not with `=`. Or with `equals()`

Comment: `char row1 = 'A','L';` this code is not correct, you can only assign one value to the char variable

Comment: Thanks :) forgot to add the second =. @pzaenger

Comment: How would I go about fixing that? I am not sure how to assign multiple characters. @JamesWierzba

Comment: I posted an easier solution as an answer

Comment: Your code starts out wrong by asking for the "student's *last* name". The assignment says to "take as input a student's **full** name".

Comment: Like @Andreas said: your expected input could be something like `Peter Griffin`, where you need to get the `G` from to sort the student accordantly (as far as I understood).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
if((initial >= 'A' && initial <= 'L') || (initial >= 'a' && initial <= 'l')){
    // If letter is between 'A' and 'L' or 'a' and 'l'
    System.out.println(" This student can sit anywhere in row 1. ");
} else if((initial >= 'M' && initial <= 'Z') || (initial >= 'm' && initial <= 'z')){
    // If letter is between 'M' and 'Z' or 'm' and 'z'
    System.out.println(" This student can sit anywhere in row 2. ");
}
```

And if the input would be **full** name add this:

```
try{
    char initial = name.split(" ")[1].charAt(0);
} catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Invalid input!");
}
```

Comment: The first part works very well thank you! When I add the last part I get an error:   

Error: The method charAt(int) in the type java.lang.String is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: I mistyped there. You should change `.charAt()` to `.charAt(0)` Editing the answer right now.

Comment: Okay awesome! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use the ascii value of the char.

```
int m = (int)'M';
name = name.toUpperCase();
int initial = (int)name.charAt(0);

if(initial < m)
{
    System.out.println(" This student can sit anywhere in row 1. ");
}
else
{
    System.out.println(" This student can sit anywhere in row 2. ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very easy solution.

Comment: I am happy to help.
 If it solves your problem, please accept the answer

Comment: There is no reason to avoid char and map everything to int.