# How do you use equals only once in this?

Tags: java, string, equals

```
if (someString.equals('a') || someString.equals('b') ||    someString.equals('c') || someString.equals('d'))
```

How to shorten this syntax do not duplicate the equals ?

Comment: You could but the chars in an array and check for any matches. You could check the range, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/33044520/438992.

Comment: Is there some guarantee that `someString` will be of length 1?

Comment: Just an aside, no `String` will ever be equal to `'a'`, or any other `char`.  Did you mean `someString.equals("a")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions (please note it is a lot slower approach than your original one):

```
if (someString.matches("[abcd]")
```

Streams:

```
if (Arrays.stream(new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d"}).anyMatch(input::equals))
```

Answer (score 2):

In your answer it seems like you are trying to compare strings.  In this case, I would use array syntax like this:

```
 final String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
 if(Arrays.asList(arr).contains("a")){
        // Do Stuff
 }
```

If you are only looking to compare single characters, @AdamSiemion's answer using Regex is spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just clarity and brevity, you could always look at the character's ASCII value.

```
char c = someString.charAt(0);
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'd'){
    // do whatever 
}
```

To understand this, you have to understand that a String is composed of a series of characters stored in an array.  (It gets more complicated, of course, but that's a good starting point.)

Each one of these characters is ultimately coded as a number.  The computer basically has a pre-built lookup table, where certain numbers reference certain characters.  In that character table, the numbers for `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` (etc) are next to each other, and rising by one each time.

It's also important to understand that when you use `'a'`, you are referencing the character.  By contrast, when you use `"a"`, you are referencing a String.  Strings can't be compared with `>`, `<`, or `==`, but characters can.  So, by extracting the first character of the String, you are permitting yourself to check numerical ranges