# How do I catergorize names based on first letter without having to list the entire alphabet?

Tags: java, string, char, substring

I'm a beginner in java and I was trying to write a bunch of names and sort them out into groups. For example, names starting from A through G are on team 1 name starting from H through R are on team 2 and so on.

However I'm running into some trouble, I can't seem to do it, here's what I got so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class nameDivisioninTeams {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter in a name");

        String name1 = in.next();

        if (name1.substring(0,1).equals ("A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G")){
            System.out.print(name1 + "is on team 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `equals ("A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G")` is not valid in Java. You may want to place those values is some set and check if such set `contain` first letter.

Comment: Or you can take first `char` via `name1,charAt(0)` and then use `<=` `>=` operators to check if it is greater or equal than `'A'` and lesser or equal than `'G'` like in [Determine if char value is in range of chars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33044520)

Comment: you can use `if ("ABCDEFG".contains(name1.subSequence(0, 1)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the properties of the [TreeSet Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are
>   ordered using their **natural ordering**, or by a Comparator provided at
>   set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-in-java-with-examples/) is an article explaining a bit more how TreeSet can be used. 
So, you can for instance:

1. add your names to a TreeSet. The names will be ordered
   alphabetically as that's the natural ordering of Strings.
2. Then you can iterate through the list assigning the names to your
   groups.

Answer (score 0):

If the letters you want to group together are consecutive in the alphabet, you can do it using regex with Pattern and Matcher classes, without having to list the entire alphabet, as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class nameDivisioninTeams {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter in a name");

    String name1 = in.next();
    Pattern patternAG = Pattern.compile("^[a-gA-G]\\S*");        
    Pattern patternHR = Pattern.compile("^[h-rH-R]\\S*");  
    Pattern patternSZ = Pattern.compile("^[s-zS-Z]\\S*");

    Matcher mAG = patternAG.matcher(name1);
    Matcher mHR = patternHR.matcher(name1);
    Matcher mSZ = patternSZ.matcher(name1);

    if(mAG.matches())
        System.out.print(name1 + "is on team 1");
    else if (mHR.matches())
        System.out.print(name1 + "is on team 2");
    else if (mSZ.matches())
        System.out.print(name1 + "is on team 3");

    }
}
```